# Display text of <select> tag different to the selected <option> tag

Tags: html

```
<select>
 <option>Option1</option>
</select>
```

When I click on the "Option1" from the drop down it should display a text like "First Option" even though its displayed in drop down as "Option1".

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Set value for option: <option value="Option1">First Option</option>

Comment: By starting the read the documentation of the tools you use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: @BhojendraNepal — The value will never be displayed. It will only be submitted with the rest of the form data.

Comment: @arkascha — RTFM comments aren't very helpful, especially when the documentation doesn't cover what the question is asking for.

Comment: @Quentin References to a good documentation are an _excellent_ oportunity for the OP to actualy _learn_ a) how to solve the issue at hand and b) how to be able to do that for subsequent questions that will arise. Apart from that: in my eyes the referenced explanation offers simple and precise examples for exactly what the OP asks about...

Comment: @arkascha — It doesn't. Perhaps you are also misreading the question in the same way that Bhojendra is?

Comment: @Quentin That might or might not be the case. We do not know what the OP _really_ wants to know. All we can do is help to our best knowledge. But it appears you know more than we do. :-)

Comment: @arkascha — The question is perfectly clear. It is just a strange thing to want. People seem to be assuming that (because it is a strange thing to want) the OP is trying to ask for something which is both completely different to what they said said and trivially easy to solve without asking for help.

Comment: (The only approach I can see that might work is to use JavaScript to change the label on the option when the select is opened and closed; detecting the opening and closing is probably non-trivial, especially cross platform, more so when you account for the different UIs selects have on iOS and Android).

Comment: Whoa! Easy there... Just tell me if what I am asking is even possible.

Comment: @Quentin To me it is _not_ clear that the OP asks what you claim is asked. So the question is _not_ clear per definition of the term. Sorry.

Comment: @pkyo — "Maybe". As I said, it is distinctly non-trivial at best.

Comment: @Quentin nice idea, but I hope there an easier solution.

Comment: @pkyo — There isn't (unless you consider "not using a select but building something out of divs and JavaScript to simulate one" being "easier" (keeping in mind such things as mobile support, screen reader support, and what happens if JS fails for any reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I devised an easier way to get through the problem.

```
<script>
 function myFunction()
         {
             if(document.getElementById("someId").selectedIndex%2==0)
                document.getElementById("someId").selectedIndex++;
         }
</script>

<select id="someId" onchange="myFunction()">
 <option        value='sameValue'> Option1     </option>
 <option hidden value='sameValue'> First Option</option>
</select>
```

I have created a 2nd option with the same value which gets selected whenever the 1st one is selected.